# Google Play doesn't authenticate properly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

When a screen button is pressed, the method `OnButtonPress()` authenticates the player and shows the leaderboard after authentication.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using GooglePlayGames;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;

public class Leaderboard : MonoBehaviour {

    void Awake() 
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate ();
    }

void OnButtonPress()
    {

        if(PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.IsAuthenticated())
                             PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowLeaderboardUI("my_leaderboardID");
             else
                             Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success)=>{
                                 PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowLeaderboardUI("my_leaderboardID");
                             });
    }
}
```

Summary - The UI button is used to:

1. If the user is not authenticated - to authenticate him and show the leaderboard.
2. If the user is authenticated - to just show the leaderboard.

The issue: when the player signs in by pressing the button once and then presses the button again, he's asked to sign in again! Also, the leaderboard and the "Welcome" popup never show up. Why isn't the authentication "saved" - how can I fix this?

Authentication used to work normally yesterday!
What did I change?

Also, in the Google Settings app: my game doesn't show up in the list of connected apps after "signing in".

Comment: why does the button stay active when the user presses first time?

Comment: @DavidH. to show the leaderboard

Comment: @DavidH. the button is used to 1) if the user is **not** authenticated - to authenticate him and show the leaderboard. 2) if the user **is** authenticated - to just show the leaderboard